# While inside While from different MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql

i have 2 tables:

1. **Cat**

id,cat_name

2. **SubCat**

id, subcat_name, under_cat

i want to make a list that loads the sub category into the correct Category 
the problem is with the second loop, i cant make it work
what am i doing wrong?

```
    <?
        $query = "SELECT * FROM `Cat`";
        $result = $mysqli->query($query);
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
            echo '<li><a href="#">'
            . $row['cat_name'] .
            '</a><ul>';
                $query2 = "SELECT * FROM `SubCat` WHERE under_cat = '". $row['cat_id'] ."'";
                $result2 = $mysqli->query($query2);
                while ($row2 = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                    echo '<li><a href="#">'
                    . $row2['subcat_name'] .
                    '</a></li>';
                }

            echo '</ul></li>';
        }
    ?>
```

**EDIT:**

[image]
two lists from same category

this is the code:

```
    <?
        $query = "SELECT * FROM Cat LEFT OUTER JOIN SubCat ON SubCat.under_cat = Cat.cat_id;";
        $result = $mysqli->query($query);
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
            echo '<li><a href="#">'
            . $row['cat_name'] .
            '</a><ul>';
                if($row['cat_id'] === $row['under_cat']){
                echo '<li><a href="#">'.$row['subcat_name'].'</a></li>';
```

}

```
            echo '</ul></li>';
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: What is it doing wrong?

Comment: Did you mean `$row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()`, by any chance?

Comment: If you use only one table for cats and subcats, you could use more than one depth and it will be easier. To do it, you could use a parent_id nullable field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hate doing `SELECT *` because of their maintenance problems, but to work with what you did, just do a `JOIN`:

```
"SELECT * FROM Cat LEFT OUTER JOIN SubCat ON SubCat.under_cat = Cat.cat_id;"
```

This will return the result set you want, but you will need to modify your PHP in response to create the list appropriately, something like this:

```
if($row['cat_id'] === $id){
    echo '<li><a href="#">'.$row2['subcat_name'].'</a></li>';
} else {
    echo '</ul></li><li><a href="#">'.$row['cat_name'].'</a><ul>';
    iF(!empty($row['subcat_name'])){
        echo '<li><a href="#">'.$row['subcat_name'].'</a></li>';
    }
}

$id = $row['cat_id'];
```

This will add the items to the list if it is the same as the previous entry, else it will start a new list. The `!empty` thing is a quick attempt at handling NULLs, as in where there were no matches brought back from `SubCat` but you had entries in `Cat`. If this would never be the case, you can eliminate the `if` statement and convert your query to this:

```
"SELECT * FROM Cat INNER JOIN SubCat ON SubCat.under_cat = Cat.cat_id;"
```

Why go through all this effort you ask? Because this will provide the result set you want while only querying **once**. The way you had it structured prior would query a bazillion times, which kills the server and greatly reduces performance.

Hopefully this helps both your problem and you're overall implementation knowledge.

Comment: Thank you my friend but this is over my level i cant make it work in your way

Comment: i tried to make it work but the problem is that its loads a new list for every sub category even if its from the same category... look at the edited post please :)